# JPA lambda Specification with null datamodel field

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have this specification with a metamodel field

```
return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) ->
criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Class_.field), compareField);
```

When a entity field (Class_.field) is null, a error was expected ([java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause)

How i can protect or not validate in null's values ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return (root, query, builder) ->     
    builder.or(    
        builder.isNull(root.get(Class_.field)),
        builder.equal(root.get(Class_.field), compareField));
```